# issue with eregi being deprecated

Tags: php-5.3

I have upgraded PHP and now I'm getting the eregi deprecated errors.

I have done some searching round web and found that I can use preg instead but not sure how to change this code correctly

```
eregi("^$row->baseUrl", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])
```

my attempt is:

```
preg_match("^$row->baseUrl/i", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])
```

but I'm not sure if this is right.

Can someone check and advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need regular expressions at all:

```
strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], 0, strlen($row->baseUrl)), $row->baseUrl) === 0
```

This grabs the prefix of `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` with at most the same length of `$row->baseUrl` and uses [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/strcasecmp) to do a case-insensitive comparison.

But if you want to use regular expressions with [PHP’s PCRE functions](http://php.net/ref.pcre), you need to use [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) (here `/` like you attempted) and quote the value properly:

```
"/^".preg_quote($row->baseUrl, "/")."/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gumbo has suggested, you don't need to use regular expressions for your particular problem. However, you should be using [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to search strings.

```
<?php
// script name is at the start of the string
stripos("{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}/", $row->baseUrl) === 0; 
// or; string name exists within the string
stripos("{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}/", $row->baseUrl) !== false;
```

You can also use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) which is a case-sensitive equivalent.

If you want to use preg_match your regular expression should be:

```
preg_match("#^{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}/#i", $row->baseUrl) === 1
```